# How to specify a temporary folder for auxiliary files for latexmk using latexmkrc for texlive?

Tags: latexmk

I am using vscodium with the LaTeX Workshop package and the TeXLive 2023 distribution in vscodium on linux to write latex documents. I want to keep my directories clean while preserving the accelerated computing that latexmk offers (inspired by [this reply](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48351/41177)).

Would the correct way to do this be to create a `.latexmkrc` in my home directory with the contents below?

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'latexmk -outdir=/tmp/latexmk -f -pdf %F; mv %f /tmp/latexmk; mv /tmp/latexmk/%b.pdf %o;'
```

Alternatively, would it also be possible to just use the `--aux-directory` flag to avoid moving around the files so much? I tried `'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode --aux-directory=/tmp/latexmk'`, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing anything else, read the latexmk documentation: for the `-auxdir`, `-emulate-aux-dir`, and `-outdir` options, for the corresponding configuration variables `$aux_dir`, `$emulate_aux`, and `$out_dir`, and the section 'AUXILIARY AND OUTPUT DIRECTORIES'.  In principle, these have all the information you need.

The method proposed in the question for configuring latexmk was copied from an answer for configuring *emacs*, and is entirely wrong for configuring latexmk.  (In addition, the answer about configuring emacs is out-of-date: It's from a time before latexmk supported the `-auxdir` option with TeXLive.)

To get the effect you need, just put the following in a `.latexmkrc` file:

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$emulate_aux = 1;
$out_dir = '.';
$aux_dir = '/tmp/latexmk';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. I used that emacs configuration reply because I used that for org mode and really liked the result. I will read the docs to get a better sense of the configuration options.